# Где сейчас активно используется с++?

Tags: c++

Изучив основные структуры данных и базовые алгоритмы и испытав их на практике, столкнулся с проблемой - куда двигаться дальше.  Хочется узнать о всех направлениях, где сейчас используется с++. Помогите найти свое место в этом жестоком мире кодинга.

Comment: Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Comment: @cppquestions, какие могут быть "прения и дискуссии" в этом вопросе? Он абсолютно конкретный -- области применения C++. Области применения языка никак не зависит ни от чьего мнения.

Comment: @eanmos зависят. Теоретически тьюринг-полный язык можно применять где угодно, но на практике разные люди применяют его в разных сферах. Одни скажут, что в вебе С++ не место, а Вася Пупкин, написавший сайт на нём, будем доказывать обратное и т.п.. Очевидно, что однозначно правильного ответа кроме "где угодно можно использовать" дать нельзя

Comment: @cppquestions Пока что бесконечные прения и дискуссии вызывает ваше замечание :)

Comment: @cppquestions, ну так автор не спрашивает "где **можно** использовать", он спрашивает о "**всех** направлениях, где **используют** (не теоретически) C++".

Comment: @cppquestions на вопрос вполне можно дать объективный ответ, сославшись, скажем, на личный опыт или результаты опросов. Не надо ничего удалять.

Comment: Хммм, если вопрос вызвал много споров о том, вызывает ли данный вопрос споры, то всё же он "порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии"?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вам не кажется, что "дать объективный ответ, сославшись на личный опыт" - противоречие? Личный опыт = субъективно = у каждого свой опыт. Объективный ответ = объективно = верно для всех

Comment: @cppquestions, что значит "у каждого свой опыт"? Может и законы физики у разных людей разные? Не надо путать "мнение" и "опыт" - это разные вещи, если для вас это одно и то же, ну, это ваше *мнение* :)

Comment: На английском SO такой вопрос закидали бы минусами минуты за две. :)

Comment: Плюсы используются во многих направлениях, но стоит ли составлять список? Есть ли у вас внутренняя планка "если Х миллионов программистов пользуются плюсами, то я буду им заниматься, а если Y - то нет"? А уж тем более неясно, как это может помочь тому, чтобы найти вам "своё место в мире кодинга": вам должен нравиться язык, а не то, сколько на нём миллионов людей пишет. А составление списка - не всегда, но один из признаков вопроса, в котором сильно играет роль мнение и количество опыта.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, что-то не закидали https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549990/in-which-area-is-c-mostly-used

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Неожиданно, но это все-таки 9 лет назад было. Почему-то мне кажется, сейчас реакция была бы другой.

Comment: Холивар уже разросся до того, что я получил секретную шапку Waffles - видимо за обилие комментариев под одним постом :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, имхо, сейчас на стэке слишком много неравнодушных людей. Лично я не вижу ничего плохо в вопросе о применении языка на сайте про вопросы по программированию. Книги по С++ - это почему-то **объективный** вопрос, а сферы применения С++ - нет.

Comment: @cppquestions, будьте добры, удалите ваш комментарий - ведь он не соответствует правилам ruSO!

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Тот вопрос оставили [как исключение](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354777/2752075).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а в чем проблема, как предложил *@VladSpirin*, сделать и такие вопросы валидными? Они вполне логичны для новичков и ничем не вредят комьюнити, это не "эй, мне тут сессию надо закрыть - напишите мне прогу".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker предлагаю вынести этот вопрос на мету, а не обсуждать тут

Comment: @RiotBr3aker А я и не говорю, что такие вопросы плохие. Просто отметил, что на англоSO порядки более строгие. Сам я не уверен, стоит их делать валидными или нет...

Comment: Проще сказать где С++ используется мало. При написании ПО под андроид используется в основном Ява. При написании ПО под эппловские устройства используются эппловские языки типа обжектив-си. При написании окон под винду используется С#. Ну а С++ в чистом виде используется там, где нужна скорость и эффективность по памяти. То есть в основном на С++ пишут библиотеки, численные методы, базы данных на нем пишут, моделирование. Библиотека Qt кстати в значительной мере на С++ написана.

Comment: Ну то есть писать-то на С++ можно для чего угодно, спасибо GCC и clang, которые генерируют код даже для утюга. Но оправданно применение С++ не везде. Например, андроид живет на разных платформах, поэтому Ява так хорошо используется для андроида, так как Ява генерит не родной код, а промежуточный код, который потом на каждом конкретном устройстве уже в родной код перекидывается. В принципе и С++ можно сделать, чтобы он генерировал промежуточный код, даже есть такие тулзы, но почему-то не пошла такая технология в массы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дадим слово Страуструпу (Книга "A Tour of C++"). В вольном подправленном гуглопереводе:

*В настоящее время C++ — очень широко используемый язык программирования. Количество его пользователей быстро увеличилось с одного в 1979 году до 400 000 в 1991 году — то есть число пользователей удваивалось примерно каждые 7,5 месяцев в течение более десяти лет. Естественно, с момента первоначального всплеска роста темпы роста замедлились, но, по моим оценкам, в 2018 году имеется около 4,5 миллиона программистов на C ++ [Kazakova2015]. Большая часть этого роста приходится на время после 2005 года, когда экспоненциальный рост скорости процессора прекратился, так что очень важным фактором стала производительность языка. Этот рост был достигнут без какого-либо маркетинга или организованного сообщества пользователей.*

*C++ — язык прежде всего индустриальный, т.е. он более заметен в производственной сфере, чем в образовании или при изучении языков программирования. Он вырос в Bell Labs, инспирированный разнообразными жесткими потребностями в области телекоммуникаций и системного программирования (включая драйверы устройств, сети и встроенные системы). Оттуда использование C++ распространилось практически на все отрасли: микроэлектроника, веб-приложения и инфраструктура, операционные системы, финансовые, медицинские, автомобильные, аэрокосмические приложения, физика высоких энергий, биология, производство энергии, машинное обучение, видеоигры, графика, анимация, виртуальная реальность и многое другое. Он в основном используется там, где стоящие перед разработчиками задачи требуют сочетания способности эффективно использовать оборудование и при этом управлять сложностью проекта. Множество применений C++ постоянно растет [Stroustrup1993, Stroustrup2014].*

Comment: Поясняю минус: при репутации 90k вы не понимаете, что на этот вопрос не следует отвечать, а его надо закрыть

Comment: @demonplus Да ради вас - что угодно :) Давайте удалим. Автор вопроса, отмените принятие ответа, без этого я удалить ответ не могу: система не дает.

Comment: Да лучше бы вопрос целиком удалить.

Comment: @demonplus,  на этот вопрос есть очень хороший ответ, и этот вопрос не  порождает бесконечные  прения и дисскусий.  Есть конкретный и хороший ответ, и к этому ответу лишь можно добавлять  что то от себя.  Думаю многим будет интересно прочитать ответ, и  сия факт означает, что вопрос даже полезен.  Я  отметил полезным и вопрос и ответ и лишь добавлю, что  С++ широко используется в робототехнике...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Кстати,вы не один - на момент написания этого комментария счет 5:3 в пользу вопроса.

Comment: Мне кажется или мнение создателя языка мягко говоря не может быть объктивным, учитывая что он не промышленный программист? Предлагаю привести тогда и мнение Линуса Торвальдса о сферах применения C++ :) Сразу будет видно, как вопрос не зависит от мнений и можно дать объективный ответ

Comment: @Harry разве такая статистика не подтверждает холиварность темы?

Comment: @cppquestions, ну так приведите его мнение и дайте "объективный" ответ, в чем проблема? Вопрос был про сферы применения, причем здесь мнение? Микроскопом тоже можно гвозди забивать, но это не значит, что сфера его применения - строительство.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker так посыл в том, что объективного ответа нет. Он зависит от мнений, о чём я и написал в первом комментарии к вопросу

Comment: @cppquestions, в каком месте он зависит от мнений? От опыта - да, от мнений - сомневаюсь. Человек попросил дать ему направление, где используется c++, он **не** спрашивал, где он не используется. Данный ответ полностью отвечает на вопрос "а где можно применить мои знания С++", хоть и достаточно поверхностно.

Comment: Не надо удалять ответ.

Comment: "Человек попросил дать ему направление, где используется c++, он не спрашивал, где он не используется" - хм, для меня это эквивалентно. "Данный ответ полностью отвечает на вопрос "а где можно применить мои знания С++"" - я не осуждаю ответ, я говорю, что вопрос не соответствует правилам ruSO

Comment: Не надо удалять ответ. Да, вопрос/ответ основан не фактах, а на мнениях (пусть и таких уважаемых людей как СтраусСтруп), но смысла удалять не вижу, раз успели дать ответ под закрытие и даже кому-то пригодилось.

Comment: @AK я не прошу удалять ответ, я прошу закрыть вопрос

Comment: @cpp questions, вы просите закрыть вопрос только ради того, чтобы  ваше мнение оказалось правильным, но вопрос полезен для новычков, а ответ по нраву даже не новычкам.  Чем вам мешает вопрос и чем он  так  вреден для читателей? Задайте эти два вопроса сами себе , заодно настраиваясь более добродушно

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вопрос и ответ конечно могут быть полезны, но они неформат для SO.